# How can i use Lerp to move an object according to mouse click position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a code that works clearly between A and B point which i choose. Now i wanna edit this code for wherever i click , the cube will go smoothly with Lerp code. I couldn't do this.
Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class LerpTest : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float start = 0.0f;
    public float end = 5.0f;
    public float delay = 1.0f;
    public float factor = 0.1f;
    public float epsilon = 0.01f;


    void Update()
    {
        if (start != end)
        {
            start = Mathf.Lerp(start, end, Time.deltaTime * factor);
            if (end - start < epsilon)
                start = end;
            transform.position = new Vector3(start, 0, 0);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What results are you currently getting with that code? Also, never compare two floating-point values dirrectly with `!=` (or `==`) operator, like in you `if (start != end)` condition. Unity3D offers the [Mathf.Approximately()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) method in case you must compare if float values are "approximately equal" to each other.

Comment: Thank you for your info.When i play it, the cube goes smoothly from start point to end point. It's ok now but i wanna change it manual way with mouse button. Like wherever i click it will go smoothly. How can i do this ?

Comment: Detect mouse click then move the object. A simple googling should get you started then update your question if you still have issues